# How to recursivly find the height of a Trie Tree

Tags: c++, tree, height, trie

I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to find the height of a trie tree data structure. I know for an AVL tree a simple recursive height function would be:

```
height(nodeType *node) const
{
  if(node == NULL)
    return 0;

  // if tree is not empty height is 1 + max of either path
  return 1 + std::max(height(node->left), height(node->right));
}
```

but now my trie tree has a children with 26 different indexes, there must be a simple way to find the maximum height without typing out all 26 different possible indexes. How could I go about this?

```
int height(trieNodeType *node) const
{
  if(node == NULL)
    return 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < 26; i ++) {
    //has to be something to do with a for loop, 
    //i know that much
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `trieNodeType`?

Comment: @cdhowie it contains a value, boolean and `trieNodeType *children[26]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping is the way to go.

C++11:

```
if (node == nullptr) return 0;

auto i = std::begin(node->children);
auto end = std::end(node->children);

auto max_height = height(i++);

while (i != end) {
    max_height = std::max(max_height, height(i++));
}

return 1 + max_height;
```

C++ <11.

```
if (node == NULL) return 0;

trieNodeType ** i = node->children;
trieNodeType ** end = i + (sizeof(node->children) / sizeof(trieNodeType *));

int max_height = height(i++);

while (i != end) {
    max_height = std::max(max_height, height(i++));
}

return 1 + max_height;
```

Comment: on the pre c++11 code I had to change i and end to be `node->children[0]` and node->children[25]`, but the program hangs and crashes. any ideas?

Comment: @SyntacticFructose My bad, `i` and `end` should be pointers-to-pointers.  Try the updated code.

Answer (score 2):

Another C++11 approach

```
return 1 + std::accumulate(std::begin(node->children) + 1, std::end(node->children), 
    height(node->children[0]),
    [](int curMax, trieNodeType* child) { return std::max(curMax, height(child)); });
```

There exists also  [std::max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) function, but in straightforward implementation using it would lead to calculating the height of the same child node several times.